# How to alter a table to add a self join relation?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table called "Users" it contain some fields such as Id, ParentId, Name.
What I want is to alter this table to add new self join relation so that ParentId link to Id, but ParentId is nullable.
I want to write this alter sql statment in mysql without dropping the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to add a foreign key constraint?  If so, see the [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) docs.  Here's an example, starting with creating a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Add an index for the `parent_id` column:

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD INDEX `parent_id` (`parent_id`);
```

Add the foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_parent_id`
FOREIGN KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`)
REFERENCES `users` (`id`);
```

Show the new table structure:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE users;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_parent_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`)
    REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
alter table Users add constraint parent foreign key (ParentId) references
  Users (Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you're working with a table that contains data, foreign key relationship creation will fail if orphaned relationships exist. Find and fix orphans prior to creating foreign keys!

SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `parent_id` NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM `users`);